# What is this website and why do they have my / our answers?

Tags: discussion

I was searching for an old account on a music site using Google and happened across something with my username on another site. I stumbled upon the site http://radioaddictsanonymous.com/ and it seems like they are direct copies of some answers / questions from the site.

Is this allowed? The website does not seem to follow all of the steps outlined in this article (points 1, 2, and 4): http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

Comment: There's a post on MSE aggregating all these sites, but it's not very useful now.  I think the guidance now (don't quote me) is to use [the contact form](http://music.stackexchange.com/contact) and provide as much detail as you can: What you searched on which search engine, how highly it ranked and how highly the real SE site ranked, etc.  If it was buried deep I wouldn't bother though.

Comment: I googled my username + a couple music terms, it was somewhere near the top of the results

Comment: For reference: Here's the full details on what to do, it is to use the contact form: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/233816 I agree this ones in violation of the attribution requirements, so should be reported...whether it's judged big enough to have any action taken can be someone else's problems. =)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Someone plagiarized an answer I wrote. What's the right thing to do?](http://meta.music.stackexchange.com/questions/720/someone-plagiarized-an-answer-i-wrote-whats-the-right-thing-to-do)

Answer (score 6):

Ah yes, scrapers. When you have as large and valuable a body of expert information as Stack Exchange does, sometimes someone out there on the internet tries to mine our content and get some page views for themselves.

I can confirm Matthew Read's advice: head on over to the [contact form](https://music.stackexchange.com/contact) and report as much info as you can about which search engine you used, which search terms you used, search ranking and so on.

This is common enough that someone from our team specializes in handling these cases. It may take some time, but we'll rectify the situation.